# Unable to get prevPageToken with blogger api v3

Tags: google-api, blogger

I'm unable to get the previous page token from blogger api v3 unlike v2. After thorough search i discovered that the prevPageToken is not included at all in returned json data. All i need is a guideline to implement a working pagination with the api.

`"prevPageToken":""`